# How to remove multiple white spaces in a multiple line text file in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, removing-whitespace

I have a text file that contains lines separated by "\n" and blank spaces in between each item. Items are separated by one or more blank spaces. However, the blank spacing in between the elements is consistent throughout each line.

```
FRUIT   WATER   GRE  LRG   0003 050
FRUIT   BANAN   YEL  MED   0017 010
FRUIT   STRAW   RED  SML   0005 005
FRUIT   LEMON   YEL  SML   0024 005
VEGIE   REDPE   RED  MED   0008 001
VEGIE   GRENP   GRE  MED   0009 001
BOX   RED     006 012 018
BOX   YEL     010 020 030
BOX   GRE     003 006 009
PERSON      JOHN  TALL  STRG
PERSON      JIMM  MEDM  WEAK
PERSON      DAVD  MEDM  STRG
```

I am trying to parse this file with PHP. The following code yields an array with many white spaces.

```
if(file_exists($filename)) {
        $filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
        $lines = explode("\n", $filecontents);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $exploded = explode(" ", $line);
        if (sizeof($exploded) >= 5 and $exploded[0] == 'FRUIT') $array[] = array(
            'type' => $exploded[1],
            'color' => $exploded[2],
            'size' => $exploded[3],
            'qty' => $exploded[4],
            'weight' => $exploded[5]
            );
        if (sizeof($exploded) >=5 and $exploded[0] == 'VEGIE') $array[] = array(
            'type' => $exploded[1],
            'color' => $exploded[2],
            'size' => $exploded[3],
            'qty' => $exploded[4],
            'weight' => $exploded[5]
            );
        if (sizeof($exploded) >= 5 and $exploded[0] == 'BOX') $array[] = array(
            'color' => $exploded [1],
            'largefit' => $exploded[2],
            'medfit' => $exploded[3],
            'smallfit' => $exploded[4]
            );
        if (sizeof($exploded) >= 4 and $exploded[0] == 'PERSON') $array[] = array (
            'name' => $exploded[1],
            'build'=> $exploded[2],
            'strength' => $exploded[3]
            );
        }
    }

print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking. to replace multiple spaces you can do `$var = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $var)` or any whitespace character `$var = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $var)`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tonight.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just a tab between each field?

Comment: I looked at the text file with an editor that identifies spaces differently from tabs. It shows the separations as spaces in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer, use `trim()` on all your values before saving them:

```
'type' => trim($exploded[1]),
```

But, this job is something that you can do more efficiently with [regular expressions](http://php.net/preg-match). Also note the [`file()`](http://php.net/file) command reads a file into an array automatically!

```
<?php
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    $array = [];
    $lines = file($filename);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (!preg_match("/(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)(?:(?:\s+(\w+))?\s+(\w+))?/", $line, $matches)) {
            continue;
        }
        switch ($matches[1]) {
            case "FRUIT":
            case "VEGGIE":
                list($foo, $bar, $type, $color, $size, $qty, $weight) = $matches;
                $array[] = compact("type", "color", "size", "qty", "weight");
                break;
            case "BOX":
                list($foo, $bar, $color, $largefit, $medfit, $smallfit) = $matches;
                $array[] = compact("color", "largefit", "medfit", "smallfit");
                break;
            case "PERSON":
                list($foo, $bar, $name, $build, $strength) = $matches;
                $array[] = compact("name", "build", "strength");
                break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

The [`compact()`](http://php.net/compact) command does the opposite of `extract()`; that is, it takes its arguments, and puts the variables with those names into an associative array.

Comment: When I try this code on the file Inactually want to process (~40MB), I get a memory error. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could use `fopen()`, `fread()`, and `fclose()` to access the file. Instead of loading the whole file at once you'd just be reading it line by line. Then just replace the `foreach` loop with a `while (!feof($fp))` loop instead.